# How can I activate a specific window of an external application in OSX?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, safari

I'm trying to control Safari windows from my application.

I use this code to get the window list from Safari via ScriptingBridge:

```
SafariApplication *saf = [SBApplication ApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:myPid];
SBElementArray *safariWindows = [saf windows];
```

This works fine so far. 
I also can manage the order of the windows with the index property something like this:

```
SafariWindow *firstSafWin = [saf.windows objectAtIndex:0];
[firstSafWin setIndex: 1];
```

Now I try to activate Safari with:

```
NSRunningApplication *runApp =  [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier: myPid];           
    [runApp activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateAllWindows];
```

**So here comes my problem:**
Safari gets activated and the window I wanted is on top now, **but it doesn't get the focus** (or "mainWindow"). So the focus of the user input is still on the safari window which had the focus before I tried to change the order of the Safari windows.

Is there a way in OSX to get the focus to the Safari window I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Accessibility API can give you this level of control but it must be enabled on the user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, what you are doing should work. You should file a bug report against Safari.